# FedEx India Shipping Method in Magento 2 is not working

Tags: magento2, shipping-methods, fedex

I am setting up **FedEx** shipping method in Magento 2 for FedEx India but it does not work.

How to setup for FedEx India? Will it work for India?

Answer (score 2):

Check you settings for all correct values and for india specific :

Update the wsdl files in Magento/Fedex/Carrier.php file

In order for the India to India domestic shipping to work you need to add in a PurposeOfShipment type to the request. This line is not standard in Magento's code for Fedex shipping. That line will be added into CustomsClearanceDetail header as a child under CommercialInvoice then a line under that is Purposewhich can have any value that PurposeOfShipment has.

Here is an example of the request I used that returned proper shipping estimates for India to India shipping.

```
'CustomsClearanceDetail' => array(
     'CommercialInvoice' => array(
       'Purpose' => "SOLD"
    )
),
```

The rates for some reason only work with production keys for me.Try the production keys if you are also having some problem with test.

Comment: I am facing the same issue in Magento 1.9 .Can you please suggest which file i have to edit as in Magento 1.9 there is no such file "carrier.php" in /magento_root/app/code/core/Mage/Shipping/Model

Comment: @SaurabhRanjan its in app\code\core\Mage\Usa\Model\Shipping\Carrier